# use Python BeautifulSoup or other method to locally save a URL and all supporting files

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a basic web scraper to create a local mirror of a remote site, using Python BeautifulSoup. I don't want to transform the data in any way, I just want to:

1. input a URL
2. go to that URL. Save the files in that directory
   and their subdirectories.
3. Save JS, CSS & image files linked from
   the saved files

I feel like this is would be a pretty common & basic use of BeautifulSoup, but can't find an example of it. Can someone direct me, or paste in an example?

---

A simpler method, as suggested below, is to use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/). I didn't know about it when I asked this question, but it is a fast and easy method to create local copies of websites.

Comment: Why not just use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/1/en/index.html)?

Comment: Because it didn't come up on any of my searches. Thanks for the reference though, it looks like exactly what I am after.

Comment: http://scrapy.org/ is pretty good tool :)

Comment: Well, actually this is a shame. Would love to see how this page will lead to python resources to build thing like HTTrack